# Including figure in IEEE template using TeXmaker

Tags: graphics

I use TeX live and try to insert a figure into the LaTeX template provided by ieee, the `bere_conf.tex`. Then I get this error message:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `fig1.png' not found.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

My figure is in the same directory. Which are the options to be enabled to include figures in ieee TeX format?

Comment: Did you try to insert the same figure using a simple document with the standard class `report` for example?

Comment: User last seen May 8 at 4:46, no reply to the comments, i vote to close as unclear.

Comment: Where can we find the `bere_conf.tex`?

Comment: Could this be re-opened? I faced the same issue and have an answer. The problem is that the IEEE template provided in a zip file, does not contain a figure along with it. The user just has to place a figure named `fig1.png` in the same folder as the `tex` file and the error will disappear. This is the template the user is referring to: https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html